# Replace (parsing "\" illegal at end of pattern)

Tags: c#

Well I have a mini program with C#, so I do this in my program

```
wordSearch = "T:\\"
wordReplace = "T:\\Gestion\\"
content = Regex.Replace(content, wordSearch, wordReplace);
```

But doesn't work. The error is:

```
parsing "T:\" - illegal \ at end of pattern.
```

Any idea ?

[Added]

Sorry! Perhaps I didn't explain well. So I try again.

I did a form taking a string for input, but if this string is "T:\", the program take "T:\". So, I save this string in variable "workShearch".

After this variable uses in:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, Regex.Escape(wordSearch), Regex.Escape(wordReplace));
```

But this line contains an error, because wordSearch in this case is "T:\", and the program throws an exception like this:

```
The error in parsing "T:\" - illegal \ at end of pattern.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but \ is an escape sequence, that's the problem. Try this: `content = Regex.Replace(content, @wordSearch, @wordReplace);`

Comment: Yes, it's an escape sequence both in Strings and Regexes, so the correct Regex is either `"T:\\\\Gestion\\\\"` or `@"T:\Gestion\"`

Comment: It's both an regex and a C# string escape character, which means it would have to be escaped twice, i.e. "T:\\\\".

Comment: The answers below are fine... but why are you using regular expressions for this? A simple string replace would suffice in this case. i.e. `content = String.Replace(wordSearch,wordReplace);`

Comment: @DatRid, Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can use the @ on variables, just on strings. The @ on variables is to distinguish them from keywords, they don't make a string variable verbatim.

Comment: @Jcl Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are right! My bad.

Comment: @DatRid I was really not trying to mock on the "correct me if I'm wrong" part, just didn't see you wrote the same! :-)

Comment: @Jcl No problem, I just found it funny! :)

Answer (score 7):

You should escape `\` in pattern. Either use `"T:\\\\"` or [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) ( advantage of verbatim strings is that escape sequences are not processed, which makes it easy to write):

```
var wordSearch = @"T:\\";
var wordReplace = @"T:\Gestion\";

content = Regex.Replace(content, wordSearch, wordReplace);
```

Comment: I think its also useful if you explain the `@` for him ;)

Answer (score 2):

Escape your '\' again.

```
wordSearch = "T:\\\\"
```

A more elegant solution would be to use the @ modifier infront of your strings

```
wordSearch = @"T:\\"
```

Answer (score 2):

`\` is escape character, if you want to have `\\`, you should type `\\\\`
or place `@` in front of your string, which will consider whole string is a plain text

```
wordSearch = @"T:\\"
wordReplace = @"T:\\Gestion\\"

// or 

wordSearch = "T:\\\\"
wordReplace = "T:\\\\Gestion\\\\"
```